# How to create and render components inside a Vue component like in React?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

In React, you can do the following:

```
export const Button = ({ icon, children, ...props }) => {

  const Icon = () => (
    icon ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fal", "check"]} className={iconPositionClass}/> : null
  );

  return (
    <BsButton children={children} {...props}>
      {iconPosition === "left" 
        ? <><Icon/>{children}</>
        : <>{children}<Icon/></>
      }
    </BsButton>
  );
};
```

I can create another component inside the first one, in this case, `<Icon />`, and then conditionally render it inside the first one, `<Button />`.

With Vue, however, it's not like that, because there is no `return`. There's just a `template` tag, and while you can create a function in the `<script>` tag, that function cannot return html.

I know that I can re-create the above code using `v-if` and `v-else` for the actual element that I want to be rendered, but that just means that I have to repeat the code inside the `<template>`. It feels too repetitive.

Is there a way to re-create the React way of doing it in Vue?

Comment: We do have render functions and JSX too: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html

Comment: You can always use render function if you miss React way of doing this. "It feels too repetitive" - what exactly? Consider providing code that needs to be fixed

Comment: @EstusFlask Well, if I can't create an `Icon` component that returns a JSX image conditionally, then I'm going to have to insert that `img` tag inside the `template`, and then maybe put it inside a wrapper with a `v-if` directive. Then I have to repeat that again for the other side of the button.

Comment: You can create comps dynamically and render them with <component is> You shouldn't generally do that, it lacks optimizations at least. Here You don't need to define `Icon` in the scope of `Button` It could be just a separate comp that accepts `icon` prop, `... <template v-if="iconPosition === "left"><Icon :icon="icon"/>{{children}}</template> ...`. Since Icon doesn't really use `icon` value, would make more sense as `<Icon v-if="icon"/>`

Comment: @EstusFlask What is the `children` here? I am guessing nothing is automatically passed as a `children` prop in Vue? But I do like the idea of creating the Icon component separately.

Comment: Children that are passed as is to a component are default slot in Vue, i.e. <slot> instead of {{children}}

Comment: @EstusFlask What do you think about this: https://jsfiddle.net/0fpujvho/ ? Do you think this is a good way of doing it? The `icon` is a prop.

Comment: Looks ok. Would be the same in React, `{{icon && iconPosition === "left" && <Icon>}}` It's unknown where iconPosition comes from, if `icon` is a bool, they could be combined